# Meta description SEO

Tags: seo

Quiero consultar sobre la sintaxis de la etiqueta meta `description` que me arroja error en el checkeo de `SEO`.
Actualmente en mi código la linea del meta description esta así:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php isset($metadescription) ?  $metadescription : $quickrabbitalias ?>" />
```

Sin embargo el reporte de `SEO` sigue arrojando el error sobre esta. Agradecería una orientación sobre este tema ya que me es de urgencia.

Comment: ¿De que error hablas? ¿De que reporte? ¿Qué salida produce ese código? La meta etiqueta `description` no es obligatoria para la SEO, por lo que es cuestión de gustos.

Comment: Toledano, creo que la meta-description para el SEO es obligatoria ya que sino no te posicionaras bien en los buscadores. De que error estas hablando DnielPO?

Comment: deberías poner un ejemplo de los posibles valores de **$metadescription** y **$quickrabbitalias**